# pos application billing page in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck to the task with pos application billings page I and to append object array images only to HTML table row but I have an issue with this part please give some solution.

```
var food={
    data:[
    {
        "SNO" :1,
        "ItemName":"cofee Black",
        "Price":"$13.50",
        "Purchased": 44,
        "Sold":14,
        "InStock" :30,
        "Type":"Drinks",
        "Status":"Available",
        "Image":"image/img1.jpg",
    },
    {
        "SNO" :2,
        "ItemName":"Tea Black",
        "Price":"$11.50",
        "Purchased": 91,
        "Sold":27,
        "InStock" :64,
        "Type":"Drinks",
        "Status":"Available",
        "Image":"image/img1.jpg",

    },
```

this is my array file I want to append image data only to the HTML table row

```
    var cart=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('food'));
    console.log(cart);
    buildTable(cart)
    function buildTable(data){
        var table=document.getElementById('myTable')
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var row=`<tr>
                <td><img src = '${data[i].Image}'></td>

                </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
        }
    }
```

this is my jquery code please give tips guys to help the task.

The exact output was like this picture.

Comment: Try `buildTable(cart.data);` or `buildTable(food);` maybe?

Comment: "*exact output was be like this picture*" - is that your *intended* output, or the output your code generates?  "output was like this" vs "output is to be like this"

Comment: no sir I want the output like example pictures

Comment: Please return and comment on suggested solutions

Answer (score 0):

Your data is to be found under the `data` property of `cart`.

So, you need to call `buildTable(cart.data)`.

The `buildTable()` is problematic too, as it will add single-column rows to your table. Using `.innerHTML` in a loop should also be avoided, as it necessitates repeated parsing and rebuilding of DOM elements. Instead you should assemble the whole HTML-string first (in the loop) and then add it *once* to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need the array called data inside food. Also you need correct JSON - I removed some trailing commas

You can simplify the loop using a map too - that is faster since you avoid multiple appends

Your code cannot give you the "exact output" since you have one image per table row. I suggest you use divs and CSS grids.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
const buildTable = data => data.map((item) => `<div style="background-image:url(${item.Image})">${item.ItemName}</div>`).join("");
const food = JSON.parse(jsonStr || `{"data":[]}`); // avoids errors if localStorage is empty
let cart = food.data;
wrapper.innerHTML = buildTable(cart);
//console.log(cart);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}

#wrapper div {
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: teal;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<script>
let jsonStr = `{ "data": [{ "SNO": 1, "ItemName": "Coffee Black", "Price": "$13.50", "Purchased": 44, "Sold": 14, "InStock": 30, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/foil-pouch-with-zipper-and-plastic-coffee-bag-packaging-isolated-on-picture-id1224085374?k=20&m=1224085374&s=612x612&w=0&h=H0Nf0JLe2zLrfW_4ZC4hxa5QordtJwFGmBcPbtw-ELo=" }, { "SNO": 2, "ItemName": "Tea Black", "Price": "$11.50", "Purchased": 91, "Sold": 27, "InStock": 64, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/teabag-picture-id182914582?k=20&m=182914582&s=612x612&w=0&h=5w_2693DRgtE67EWV7rQeiy62-UU21Yy6I-HFTB8hGk=" },{ "SNO": 1, "ItemName": "Coffee Black", "Price": "$13.50", "Purchased": 44, "Sold": 14, "InStock": 30, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/foil-pouch-with-zipper-and-plastic-coffee-bag-packaging-isolated-on-picture-id1224085374?k=20&m=1224085374&s=612x612&w=0&h=H0Nf0JLe2zLrfW_4ZC4hxa5QordtJwFGmBcPbtw-ELo=" }, { "SNO": 2, "ItemName": "Tea Black", "Price": "$11.50", "Purchased": 91, "Sold": 27, "InStock": 64, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/teabag-picture-id182914582?k=20&m=182914582&s=612x612&w=0&h=5w_2693DRgtE67EWV7rQeiy62-UU21Yy6I-HFTB8hGk=" } ,{ "SNO": 1, "ItemName": "Coffee Black", "Price": "$13.50", "Purchased": 44, "Sold": 14, "InStock": 30, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/foil-pouch-with-zipper-and-plastic-coffee-bag-packaging-isolated-on-picture-id1224085374?k=20&m=1224085374&s=612x612&w=0&h=H0Nf0JLe2zLrfW_4ZC4hxa5QordtJwFGmBcPbtw-ELo=" }, { "SNO": 2, "ItemName": "Tea Black", "Price": "$11.50", "Purchased": 91, "Sold": 27, "InStock": 64, "Type": "Drinks", "Status": "Available", "Image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/teabag-picture-id182914582?k=20&m=182914582&s=612x612&w=0&h=5w_2693DRgtE67EWV7rQeiy62-UU21Yy6I-HFTB8hGk=" }  ] }`;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a variable pos for the number of fields in a row
and a div for the table:

```
var pos = 4;
const obj = JSON.parse(food);
var HTML = "<table border=1><tr>";
for(j=0;j<obj.data.length;j++)
{
if((j % pos) == 0)
{
HTML += "</tr><tr>";
}
HTML += "<td align=center>"+`${obj.data[j].ItemName}`+"<img src ="+`${obj.data[j].Image}`+"></td>";
}
HTML += "</tr></table>";
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = HTML;
}


<div id="myTable"></div>
```